# TFS includes more changes than expected when checking in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Sometimes Check In option is available in the Project context menu itself, sometimes you have to go to Source Control submenu to find Check In option.
What is the difference?

Sometimes when I check in code into TFS, I notice all other solutions that have not been checked in yet get included in the list. Is this normal? Am I doing something incorrectly?